# A WPF project that uses MVVM. How to resolve the CS8618 warning on the properties of the model?

Tags: c#

[CS8618 - Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8618)#nonnullable-reference-not-initialized)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
namespace Models
{
    internal class GroupInfo
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; } // warn cs1618 for UserName here

        [JsonPropertyName("group")]
        public string Group { get; set; }//  warn cs1618 for Group here

    }
}
```

I tired to use string? to avoid CS8618  warning，but I think this is not a good way.

```
public string? UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can disable warning by `#nullable disable warnings` if you want. See [Nullable context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts).

Comment: You could also just give them default initializers when you declare the property.  e.g `public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;`

Comment: `string?` seems perfect to me because it looks like this will be deserialized from json and so those properties could be null. Adding default initializers just hides the potential issue.